# ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughOrderError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a has_one association between 3 models, but it have an error that says "ActionView::Template::Error (Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Policy#intermediary' which goes through 'Policy#invoice' before the through association is defined.)"

policy model

```
class Policy < ApplicationRecord

    self.table_name = "gipi_polbasic"
    self.primary_key = "policy_id"

    has_one :invoice
    has_one :intermediary, through: :invoice, foreign_key: :intrmdry_intm_no
```

intermediary model

```
class Intermediary < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "giis_intermediary"
    self.primary_key = "intm_no"

    has_one :invoice, foreign_key: :intrmdry_intm_no
    belongs_to :policy, foreign_key: :policy_id
```

invoice model

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "gipi_comm_invoice"
    self.primary_key = "intrmdry_intm_no"

    belongs_to :policy, foreign_key: :policy_id
    belongs_to :intermediary, foreign_key: :intrmdry_intm_no
```

Comment: Is using through with intermediary in Policy the right thing? I dont think so. It will be right if intermediary belongs to invoice not invoice belongs to intermediary.

Comment: tried it but it still show the same error

Comment: its working on the previous version of rails, the error appeared after i updated to rails 5.1.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For anyone else - see their thread https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29123

What solved it for me was to switch the order of the has_ones

```
has_one :intermediary, through: :invoice, foreign_key: :intrmdry_intm_no
has_one :invoice
```

Comment: I placed my belongs_to code above my has_many code which solved it for me. Cheers for the hint!

Comment: Also check to see if you defined the relation twice -- in Rails 4.x they'd let this slide but in 5.x it is an error (as it should be!)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a technique for finding duplicate association definitions, in case you have models made up of several monkey patches.

First, find the `has_many` method:

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods.instance_method(:has_many).source_location
```

Then, edit that file:

```
    def has_many(name, scope = nil, options = {}, &extension)
      $has_manies ||= {}                               # <- Added
      $has_manies[[name, self]] ||= []                 # <- Added
      $has_manies[[name, self]] << [options,caller[0]] # <- Added
      reflection = Builder::HasMany.build(self, name, scope, options, &extension)
      Reflection.add_reflection self, name, reflection
    end
```

Then catch the HasManyThroughOrderError and start a debugger. Evaluate this:

```
$has_manies[[:intermediary, Policy]]
```

You'll see not only whether that association is defined more than once, but also where the definitions happened.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have another redundant `has_one :intermediary` in your `Policy` model. Got the same error after update.

Comment: i dont have one, isnt it a bug on rails 5.1.1? because my app is working on rails 5.0.3

Comment: I got exactly the same error when updated from 5.0.3 to 5.1.1.

Actually I do have a lot of relationships in that model, so I didn't notice that at first glance :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the new rule is that a relation needs to be defined before it can be used.

For example, this doesn't work in rails 5.1

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phone_calls,
           :through => :phone_call_participants,
           :source => :phone_call
  has_many :phone_call_participants, :as => :participant
end
```

But this does:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phone_call_participants, :as => :participant
  has_many :phone_calls,
           :through => :phone_call_participants,
           :source => :phone_call
end
```

I'm guessing that this speeds up code interpretation since the file wouldn't have to be scanned as many times?

Comment: You're wrong about the code interpretation theory. This error is raised after scanning a the keys of a `Hash`, as obtained by calling that Hash's `keys` method. If the keys aren't in the expected order, an error is raised.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.